# No plural forms for "reputation"

Tags: bug, localization, russian-stackoverflow, plurals, transifex

Keys: [`6fed0ce6808435a1b1cff1c17a4c957a`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40266952?q=key%3A6fed0ce6808435a1b1cff1c17a4c957a) and [`8d9bec4f224970e231041639de877092`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40266818?q=key%3A8d9bec4f224970e231041639de877092).

[image]

Should be "репутации".

Comment: No, it should be "репутаций" ;)

Comment: @TheSimpliFire :D

Comment: I’m not sure that mentioned Transifex strings are related here.

Comment: @alexolut that's the only strings I've found by text =/

Comment: To the close voters: localization issues are on-topic here as they are applicable to multiple sites. If you choose to close it, pick a better reason.

Comment: btw, "репутация" is uncountable word..

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan 100 баллов репутации.

Comment: @Suvitruf so, it should be "баллов репутации" (not just "репутации" as you proposed)

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan related discussion https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7885/15479

Comment: Another note to close voters: there are *two* SE sites in the Russian language. The close reason specifically states it's for questions about *one* site. (cc @rene, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/59849)